# Emulate FTP Connection for my program

Tags: c#, ftp

I'm writing a program in C# which will connect to an FTP location and read an XML file, and want to test this locally.

How might I go about creating an FTP site on my machine so that I can do this?

My program's code (probably not necessary to answer this question?) is:

```
    private string LoadFTPFile()
    {
        string xml = null;
        string ftpAddress = "ftp://" + ftpLocation + "/" + PrintMachineParameters_BaseName + ".xml";
        try
        {

            logging.Write("Info", "LoadFTPFile()", "XML loaded from PLC: " + ftpAddress);

            WebClient request = new WebClient();
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUserName, ftpPassword);
            byte[] fileData = request.DownloadData(ftpAddress);

            xml = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(fileData);

            try
            {
                XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                xml = xml.Substring(xml.IndexOf("<"));
                xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);
                XmlNode xmlNode = xmlDoc;
                xml = xmlNode.InnerXml;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                string message = "Error loading FTP file: " + ftpAddress + Environment.NewLine;
                DisplayException("Error loading FTP file", message, exception);
                xml = null;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            string message = "Error loading FTP file: " + ftpAddress + Environment.NewLine;
            DisplayException("Error loading FTP file", message, exception);
            xml = null;
        }

        return xml;
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to emulate? There are tons of free and easy-to-use FTP servers out there.

Answer (score 0):

Install an FTP server like FileZilla, it's a free FTP server and works well for me :)

https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=server

Answer (score 0):

Create your own on your local machine.

If you don't want to install FTP software (for whatever reason), use IIS:

http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-the-ftp-service/creating-a-new-ftp-site-in-iis-7